# Dealing with resizing in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, resize

I've got three sections of my code which i'm looking to improving when browser resizing takes place. Essentially e.g. assuming the site were to be displayed on a mobile device or table, I would like these sections of the code to resize accordingly.

The first is the horizontal menu bar with a white background. Here's its [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/S5bKq/1193/) and below is the HTML.

```
        <li><a href="#">OPTION 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">OPTION 2</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">OPTION 3</a>
            <ul class="">
                <li><a href="#">OPTION 3 A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">OPTION 3 B</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">OPTION 3 C</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">OPTION 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">OPTION 5</a></li>

    </ul>
```

The second section is the calendar table. Here's its [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ntzxydhk/1/) and below is the HTML.

```
  <div id="calendar_div_accordion">
      <div id="calendar_header_one_id" class="calendar_header_div">FIRST</div>

      <div class="calendar_div_accordion_nested_divs">

        <a id="btnPrev" class="btn_prev"><<</a>

        <a id="btnNext" class="btn_next">>></a>  

        <div  id="divCalendar"></div> 
      </div>

      <div class="calendar_header_div">SECOND</div>

      <div class="calendar_div_accordion_nested_divs"> test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test</div>

      <div class="calendar_header_div">THIRD</div>

      <div class="calendar_div_accordion_nested_divs"> test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test</div>
  </div>
```

The final section is the top/first horizontal menu bar with a navy blue white background. Below is the HTML:

```
      <nav id="topbar"> 
      <a id="logo_link" href="">LOGO</a>

      <ul>
          <li><a href='#'>HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>CONTACT</a></li>   
      </ul>
  </nav>
```

And its CSS:

```
/* Logo text */
#logo_link {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Tahoma, Sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 40px;    
    color: #F5F5F5;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Top bar */
#topbar {
    background: #08445A;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px #808080;
    float: left;
}
```

With regards to taking resizing into consideration whilst styling Is there a common error I'm making?

Thanks.

Comment: Generally speaking, you'll want to use [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to control the styling on smaller devices. Specifically, that `230px` left margin won't be doing you any favours on mobile, so you'll probably want to remove that on devices less than `768px` wide (or any width you deem suitable). I don't see any media queries in your code, so you should look into setting them up.

Comment: If you are looking for a responsive display I would strongly recommend to use a CSS framework like Bootstrap. Otherwise you may spend quite a lot of time figuring out how to fit the CSS for thye different resolutions.